# Анимация абстракции

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas, html5-canvas

Есть вот такая абстракция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

знаю что через canvas такое анимируется, но не силен в данной области, может кто видел или знает как анимировать?

Comment: Вы приводите статическую картинку и говорите об анимации.

Comment: так вот у меня только она и есть увы(((

Comment: так а как анимацию Вы себе представляете? сетка колеблется "как поверхность воды" упрощенно ?

Comment: ну я глянув на картинку понял сразу как, линии крутятся по кругу вот сайт, тут похожая анимация https://www.ciklum.com/

Comment: ну скажем так, необходимо посчитать положения точек в трехмерном пространстве, а затем спроецировать их на экран.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примерная анимация на Three.js

```js
var planeVertShader = `
#define PI 3.1415926
uniform float time;
uniform float amplitude;
uniform float waveLength;
uniform vec3 pos;
uniform float timeSpeed;
uniform float planeHeight;
uniform float initRotation;
uniform float speedRotation;
varying vec3 varPos;
void main() {

  vec3 p = position + pos + vec3(0., .1, 0.);
  float wLength = 1. / waveLength;
  float heightNormal = position.y / planeHeight;
  float oneRound = heightNormal * PI * 4.;
  //вращение
  p.y += sin(p.x * wLength + time) * cos(p.z * wLength  + time) * amplitude;
  p.x = cos(-time * speedRotation + oneRound + initRotation) * position.x;
  p.z = sin(-time * speedRotation + oneRound + initRotation) * position.x;

  //скручивание
  p.x += cos(-time * speedRotation + oneRound) * heightNormal * 5.;
  p.z += sin(-time * speedRotation + oneRound) * heightNormal * 5.;

  p += pos + vec3(0., .1, 0.);

  varPos = position;

  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( p, 1.0 );
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
`;
var planeFragShader = `
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.366,0.048,0.515,1.000);
}
`;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 25, 150);
camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 1.57);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}, false);

// plane
var planes = [];
var planeHeight = 125;
var planeWidth = 15;
var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeWidth, planeHeight, 15, 100);
planeGeom.translate(4, 0, 0);
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let pos = new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 110);

    let plane = new THREE.LineSegments(planeGeom, new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
            time: {
                value: 0
            },
            amplitude: {
                value: 5
            },
            waveLength: {
                value: Math.PI * 5
            },
            pos: {
                value: pos
            },
            timeSpeed: {
                value: THREE.Math.randFloat(Math.PI * .5, Math.PI)
            },
            planeHeight: {
                value: planeHeight
            },
            initRotation: {
                value: THREE.Math.randFloat(0, Math.PI)
            },
            speedRotation: {
                value: THREE.Math.randFloat(Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI)
            }
        },
        vertexShader: planeVertShader,
        fragmentShader: planeFragShader
    }));
    scene.add(plane);
    planes.push(plane)
}

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var t = 0;
var delta = 0;
render();

function render() {

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    delta = clock.getDelta();
    t += delta;
    planes.forEach(sw => {
        sw.material.uniforms.time.value = t
    });
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Ты чернокнижник!! Чур тебя!! Что это такое, маг? Как это работает??

Comment: Супер, не догоняю я этого Three.js (((( если не сложно, а как можно поменять направление анимации, весьма благодарен!!

Comment: @Karalahti направление анимации можно поменять изменив параметр t (t -= delta;). Так же можно поиграться со значениями time вращения/скручивания в коде шейдера.

Comment: Огромное тебе спасибо!! Тебе цены нету)))

Answer (score 1):

**WebGL**. Поверхность задана при помощи `signed distance`, на нее наложен математический шум, который сдвигается со временем. Поверхность находится при помощи `raymarch`, все это дело вычисляется во фрагментном шейдере.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 coords;
  void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float; 
  uniform vec4 mr; 
  uniform float time; 

  #define rot(a) mat2(cos(a),-sin(a),sin(a),cos(a))

  #define hash31(p) fract(sin(dot(p,vec3(127.1,311.7, 74.7)))*43758.5453123)

  float noise3(vec3 p) {
      vec3 i = floor(p);
      vec3 f = fract(p); f = f*f*(3.-2.*f); 
      return mix( mix( mix(hash31(i+vec3(0,0,0)),
                           hash31(i+vec3(1,0,0)),f.x),
                       mix(hash31(i+vec3(0,1,0)),
                           hash31(i+vec3(1,1,0)),f.x), f.y), 
                  mix( mix(hash31(i+vec3(0,0,1)),
                           hash31(i+vec3(1,0,1)),f.x),
                       mix(hash31(i+vec3(0,1,1)),
                           hash31(i+vec3(1,1,1)),f.x), f.y), f.z);
  }

  float fbm3(vec3 p) {
      float v = 0.,  a = .5;
      mat2 R = rot(.37);
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          p *= 2.;
          a /= 2.;
          p.xy *= R; 
          p.yz *= R;
          v += a * noise3(p);
      }
      return v;
  }

  float map( in vec3 pos ){
      
      return pos.y + fbm3(vec3(pos.x+time,pos.yz));
  }

  float rayMarch( in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd, float tmax ){
      float t = 0.0;
      float h = (1.0-ro.y)/rd.y;
      for( int i=0; i<10; i++ ){        
          vec3 pos = ro + t*rd;
          float h = map( pos );
          if( h<0.001 || t>tmax ) break;
          t += h;
      }
      return t;    
  }

  vec3 render( in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd ) {
      vec3 col = vec3(0.); 
      float t = rayMarch( ro, rd, 10. );    
      vec3 pos = ro + t*rd;
      vec2 scp = sin(23.*pos.xz);
      col += 2.0*exp(-5.0*abs(scp.x));
      col += 2.0*exp(-5.0*abs(scp.y));
      return col*0.5*exp(-0.1*t*t);
  }

  mat3 setCamera( in vec3 ro, in vec3 rt, in float cr ) {
    vec3 cw = normalize(rt-ro);
    vec3 cp = vec3(sin(cr), cos(cr),0.0);
    vec3 cu = normalize( cross(cw,cp) );
    vec3 cv = normalize( cross(cu,cw) );
    return mat3( cu, cv, -cw );
  }

  void main(void) {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy/mr.zw;
   vec2 p = uv-0.5;
    float an = time*0.5 + 6.0*mr.x/mr.z;
    vec3 ro = vec3( 2.0*cos(an), 1.0, 2.0*sin(an) );
    vec3 rt = vec3( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    mat3 cam = setCamera( ro, rt, 0.35 );
    vec3 rd = normalize( cam * vec3( p, -1.0) );
    vec3 c = render( ro, rd )*vec3( 0.3, 0.4, 0.8 );
    gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.0 ); 
  }

`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let coords = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(coords, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coords);

let mr = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'mr');
let time = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');

let x = 0, y = 0;
let changeCenter = e => {
  e = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
  let z = window.getComputedStyle(canvas).zoom || 1;
  let d = document.documentElement;
  x = (e.clientX + d.scrollLeft - canvas.offsetLeft*z) / z;
  y = (e.clientY + d.scrollTop - canvas.offsetTop*z) / z
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => changeCenter(e));
window.addEventListener('touchmove', e => changeCenter(e));
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

resize();

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform4f(mr, x, y, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.uniform1f(time, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
      return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
    }).join('\n'));
    throw message;
  }
}

function resize(){
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  draw();
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0; overflow:hidden"><canvas/></body>
```